# Change Value in Existing Column based on Conditions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements, pandas-groupby

[image]

Hi, for each grouping (based on animal and colour), I would like to check the Action = 'See' if it is 'No' in the Check column. If it is 'No' for Action = 'See', then the particular grouping would be 'No' in the Check column.

If Action = See and Check = Yes, remains as the old value (refer to Tiger, White)

```
animallist= df['Animal'].unique().tolist()
colourlist= df['Colour'].unique().tolist()

for i in animallist:
   for j in colourlist:
       df = df[(df['Animal'] == i) & (df['Colour'] == j)]
       df['Check'] = np.where((df['Action'] == 'See') & (df['Check'] == 'no'), 'no', 
                     df['Check'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is:  change the value of the 'Correct?' column only when certain other columns have a certain value.  Otherwise, leave the 'Correct?' column alone.  You can create various test for changing column values.  Here are two examples:

```
# if Action == View and Colour = Red, then set correct to yes
# regardless of what Correct? was before

df.loc[(df['Action'] == 'View') & (df['Colour'] == 'Red'), 'Correct?'] = 'Yes'

# similar to above, but change Correct? only if it was not already 'Yes'

df.loc[(df['Action'] == 'View') & (df['Colour'] == 'Red')  & (df['Correct?'] == 'No'), 'Correct?'] = 'Yes'

# create a new correction column, default to No
# change to yes only under certain conditions

df['new_correct'] = 'No'
df.loc[(df['Action'] == 'View') & (df['Colour'] == 'Red'), 'new_correct'] = 'Yes'
```

To find all animals that have certain criteria, then change the main df based on that criteria, you can do things like:

```
df_no = df[(df['Colour'] == 'Red') & (df['Action'] == 'View') & (df['Correct?'] == 'No')].drop_duplicates()

df_no = df_no[[df_no['Animal']]   # keep only the 'Animal' column

df = df.merge(df_no, on='Animal', how='left', indicator = 'True').
df.loc[df['_merge'] == 'both', 'Correct?'] = 'no'
```

You can do more complicated things with the same idea.  You need to figure out if, for example, an animal has both 'yes' and 'no' for 'Correct?' then what do you want to do.

Comment: able to do condition based on each grouping from Animal column? @Hammurabi

Comment: Yes, for example, you can test for df['Animal'] == 'tiger', or you can do more complex things like use groupby to create a new dataframe with only 1 row per animal, figure out what values you want per animal, then merge onto the original dataframe on animal.  I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i am trying to look for each animal grouping, if the colour is red and (action is view and correct? is no), then that particular animal grouping (Eg. tiger) then it will be No for correct? column for all rows in the tiger, red, and all actions @Hammurabi

Comment: You can filter a df to find all animal groupings with certain column values, then merge onto the main df to change correct? by animal.  I'll add an example to the answer.

Comment: if using the method of filter then merge, if those animal that do not have Action: See, will not be in dataframe? Or have another filter to filter animal without Action: See and its other Actions ?